# How to apply mean function over elements of a list in R

Tags: r, list, lapply

I have a list and I want to use `lapply()` to compute the mean of its elements. For example, for the seventh item of the list I have:

```
>list[[7]]
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

and my output should be:

```
> mean(temp[[7]][1:10])
[1] 1
```

But when I use `lapply()` like below the result would be something else. What should I do?

```
> lapply(list[[7]][1:10],mean)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1
.
.
.
[[10]]
[1] 1
```

Comment: if you use `lapply` over a single element of the list, you're going to take the mean of each element of the vector.  use `lapply(list, mean)` instead.  Also, using `list` as a variable name is a bad idea since its an important function!

Answer (score 15):

To get the mean of the 7th element of the list just use `mean(list[[7]])`.
To get the mean of each element of the list use `lapply(list,mean)`.
And it's a really bad idea to call your list `list`.

Comment: Thank you :) and I will change the name as well

Comment: @hora if you feel this answer provided you with an adequate description of what you were looking for, feel free to accept it as correct by checking the grey check mark below the score.

Answer (score 12):

consider using `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

```
# sample data
a<- 1:3
dat <- list(a, a*2, a*3)

# sapply gives a tidier output
> sapply(dat, mean)
[1] 2 4 6

> lapply(dat, mean)
[[1]]
[1] 2

[[2]]
[1] 4

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

---

Also, you might want to take a look at the `plyr` package.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega) also does a good job of explaining the different *apply functions